# Cordova InAppBrowser performance issue on Android

Tags: cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

Environment
Ubuntu 22.04.3
Cordova 12.0.1
Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1
Gradle 7.6
openjdk 11.0.22
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 6.0.0
android 12.0.1

I have an app that I built in Cordova for Android that loads a website via inappbrowser. I use the '_blank' option so that I can use the eventlisteners. It has worked fine until lately as it now slows down and becomes unusable after about 30 seconds. This seems to be happening only on Android 11 and upwards. Scroll is choppy and then ceases to work at all. If I use the '_self' option which loads webview, the website site can be used fine but the eventlisteners are not accessible which is something that I really require. I have no idea why this has happened, introduced by an update to Android?
I have tried loading a simple html page with no includes, styles etc and even that is grinding to a halt after a few mins. I have tried lower versions of the Cordova Android platform and also lower versions of Inappbrowser but the outcome is still the same.
Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening or can anyone suggest a better way of loading a webview with eventlisteners, or recommend a better framework perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: I've found that if I uninstall the latest Webview update, performance goes back to normal and there is no stutter of gradual slowdown. If I install the latest Beta Webview version from Google Play store, this fixes the issues also. This looks like an issue with an Android update of the system Webview app.